# Google Cloud Messaging push notifications (with Urban Airship) only show on Android 4.0+ , not 2.3 Gingerbread

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

In this setup I'm using Urban Airship for the backend, GCM to push the notifications and then a small array of 2.3/4.0/4.1+ devices.

All devices register successfully with GCM (I can confirm this in the console). Urban Airship also has no problem sending the notifications, the API keys are set up correctly.

Therefore I think something might be wrong with the manifest file as the 2.3 device never receives the notification. All the other 4.0 devices receive them, just not the 2.3 device. It could be a problem with that particular device but I only have the one 2.3 device to test with.

Would anyone mind having a look at the Android manifest file to see if I've made an obvious error?

Much appreciated.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
<permission
        android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
        android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.MyTestApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.activity.PhotoBrowserActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_PHOTO_BROWSER"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- <activity -->
    <!-- android:name=".activity.testContentActivity" -->
    <!-- android:screenOrientation="portrait" -->
    <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> -->
    <!-- <intent-filter> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_PHOTO_GRID"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_FEED_PHOTO_GRID"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_PLAYER_PROFILE"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_FEED_NEWS"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_FEED_PODCAST"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_FEED_LATEST_VIDEO"/> -->
    <!-- <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.SHOW_test_CONTENT_FEED_HIGHLIGHTS"/> -->


    <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> -->
    <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    <!-- </activity> -->

    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.info.CustomActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.info.PushNotificationSettings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name=".stats.PlayerProfilesListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.stats.refactored.tables.TableActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.matches.MatchesSettingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.matches.matchcentre.MatchcentreActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.news.refactored.full.NewsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.START_NEWS"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.news.refactored.full.VideoPlaybackActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.activity.PhotosBrowserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.info.WallpapersActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

    <!-- Receiver for audio player -->

    <receiver android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.news.refactored.full.AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.AudioCommentaryBroadcastReceiver.STOP_AUDIO_PLAYBACK"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
            android:name=".stats.refactored.players.PlayerProfileDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_player_profile_details"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <!-- Widget -->


    <!-- Widget providers -->

    <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.ConfigurationActivityScores"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetProviderScores4x1"
            android:label="test Fixtures (small)"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidgetprovider_scores_4x1"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetProviderScores4x2"
            android:label="test Fixtures (large)"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidgetprovider_scores_4x2"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Was not included in specification -->
    <!--
                <receiver android:name=".widget.AppWidgetProviderScores4x4"
                android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
                <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/appwidgetprovider_scores_4x4"/>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    -->

    <receiver
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetProviderNews4x1"
            android:label="test News"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidgetprovider_news_4x1"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- End of widget providers -->


    <!-- Widget services -->

    <receiver
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetUpdateServiceManager"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.REGISTER_WIDGET_TYPE"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.UNREGISTER_WIDGET_TYPE"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.START_UPDATE_SERVCIE"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.CHANGE_UPDATE_SERVCIE_INTERVALS"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.STOP_UPDATE_SERVCIE"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.REFRESH_WIDGET"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetUpdateServiceScores"
            android:label="WidgetUpdateServiceScores"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.scores.UPDATE_APP_WIDGETS"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.scores.NEXT_WIDGET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.scores.PREVIOUS_WIDGET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.scores.REFRESH_WIDGET"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
            android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.AppWidgetUpdateServiceNews"
            android:label="WidgetUpdateServiceNews"
            android:process=":com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.process">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.news.UPDATE_APP_WIDGETS"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.news.NEXT_WIDGET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.news.PREVIOUS_WIDGET_CONTENT"/>
            <action android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.widget.news.REFRESH_WIDGET"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- End of Widget services -->


    <!-- End of widget -->


    <!-- REQUIRED -->



    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver">

        <!-- REQUIRED IntentFilter - For Helium and Hybrid -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship GCM -->
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
            <category android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.MyTestApplication" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- REQUIRED for detecting when the application is upgraded so it can request a new GCM ID -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"
        android:label="Push Notification Service" />
    <!-- REQUIRED only with UA Android lib version 2.1.4 and earlier. Do not include PushWorkerService with UA Android lib version 3.0.0+ since it has been deprecated -->

    <service
        android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"
        android:label="Event Service" />

    <!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
    <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name + ".urbanairship.provider" in the android:authorities -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mycompany.MyTest.urbanairship.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true" />
    <!-- END OF REQUIRED ITEMS -->


    <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
    <receiver android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.gcm.IntentReceiver"/>

    <!-- End of C2DM -->

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change :

```
<category android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest.MyTestApplication" />
```

by :

```
<category android:name="com.mycompany.MyTest" /> <!-- Just the package name of you app -->
```